# ASP.NET MVC - ActionResult calling another JsonResult to get data?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Can I call a JsonResult method from my ActionResult? What I'm trying to do is to have an Area in my MVC.Site project to deal specifically with API (just return json so that I can reuse with non-mvc projects). And then from a different ActionResult (where I deal with data AND views), I would like to call the JsonResult and then return that Json data along with View information. i.e:

```
public JsonResult GetSongs()
{
    var songs = _music.GetSongs(0, 3);
    return Json(new { songs = songs }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}

public ActionResult Songs()
{
    // Get the data by calling the JsonResult method
    var data = GetSongs();
    return Json(new
    {
        // Render the partial view + data as json
        PartialViewHtml = RenderPartialViewToString("MyView", data),
        success = true
    });
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Yes**, that is perfectly acceptable.

All `Results` inherit from `ActionResult`. Have a look at [this article](http://weblogs.asp.net/rajbk/archive/2010/05/03/actionresult-types-in-mvc2.aspx) for detailed information on `ActionResult` class.

```
public JsonResult GetSongs()
{
    var songs = _music.GetSongs(0, 3);
    return Json(new { songs = songs }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
public ActionResult GetSongs()
{
    var result = GetSongs();
    return Json(new
    {
        // The JsonResult contains additional route data and view data. 
        // Your view is most likely interested in the Data prop (new { songs = songs })
        // depending on how RenderPartialViewToString is written you could also pass ViewData
        PartialViewHtml = RenderPartialViewToString("MyView", result.Data),
        success = true
    }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: I think you missed understand my question, I know I can return Json even though the return type is `ActionResult`. My question is can I call a JsonResult method inside my ActionResult? Because for now, if I call the JsonResult method inside my ActionResult method, what I get in return is something like: `Controller: "Music", Action: "GetSongs", RouteValueDictionary: [ .. ... `

Comment: Well, if all you are interested in is the data, then you can use the `JsonResult.Data` property. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Josiah, if both methods (`JsonResult` and `ActionResult`) are from the same controller, then I can get the data. But if the JsonResult is from a different controller (and this controller is from a different Area - I've used Areas to separate the API stuffs), the Data is always null (well because it seems like the JsonResult method never get called.) How do I call the method from a different controller/area? Thanks.